# How to close a socket connection in script?

Tags: php, sockets

Im using SocketServer.class.php to do connection from a GPS tracking unit to my server. A quick example of whats happening.

Unit connects to my server, connection is established and data/buffer is sent to server and the unit disconnects and this tells the socket to close. But on some versions of the units the unit does not close the connection and the socket stays open which then holds up the process of the other units connecting and sending their information. How or what php code can I use to close a connection/socket from a unit after a curtain time or do a socket timeout after a while?

Because this creates two problems for me. I can either have the one or the other.
1) Close the connection after the first batch of information is sent/received. But the information that the unit sometimes sends through is in 3 buffer sends (hope i said that correctly) so now i keep the connection/socket open and wait for the unit to say "I'm done, close the socket". That works fine. But then the problem arises when the unit doesn't say "I'm done" and the socket stays open but all information is received.
 Here is the code I have:

```
<?php
class SocketServer
{
    protected $config;
    protected $master_socket;
    public $max_clients = 99999;
    public $max_read = 32768;
    public $clients;
    public $complete_string = "";

    public function __construct($bind_ip,$port)
    {
        set_time_limit(0);
        $this->hooks = array();

        $this->config["ip"] = $bind_ip;
        $this->config["port"] = $port;

        $this->master_socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        socket_bind($this->master_socket,$this->config["ip"],$this->config["port"]) or die("Port ".$this->config["port"]." is still open\r\n");
        socket_getsockname($this->master_socket,$bind_ip,$port);
        socket_listen($this->master_socket);
        SocketServer::debug("Listenting for connections on {$bind_ip}:{$port}");
    }

    public function loop_once()
    {
        // Setup Clients Listen Socket For Reading
        $read[0] = $this->master_socket;
        for($i = 1; $i <= $this->max_clients; $i++)
        {
            if(isset($this->clients[$i]))
            {
                $read[$i + 1] = $this->clients[$i]->socket;
            }
        }


        // Set up a blocking call to socket_select
        if(socket_select($read,$write = NULL, $except = NULL, $tv_sec = 8) < 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle new Connections
        if(in_array($this->master_socket, $read))
        {
            for($i = 1; $i <= $this->max_clients; $i++)
            {
                if(empty($this->clients[$i]))
                {
                    $temp_sock = $this->master_socket;
                    $this->clients[$i] = new SocketServerClient($this->master_socket,$i);
                    SocketServer::debug("Client {$i} from {$this->clients[$i]->ip} connected @ ".date("d-M-Y H:i:s"), time());
                    break;
                }
                elseif($i == ($this->max_clients-1))
                {
                    SocketServer::debug("Too many clients... :( ");
                }
            }

        }

        // Handle Input
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++) // for each client
            {
                if(isset($this->clients[$i]))
                {
                    if(in_array($this->clients[$i]->socket, $read))
                    {
                        $input = socket_read($this->clients[$i]->socket, $this->max_read);
                        if($input == null)
                        {
                            $this->disconnect($i);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            $this->clients[$i]->complete_string .= $input;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
    }

    public function disconnect($client_index,$message = "")
    {
        $i = $client_index;
        SocketServer::debug("Lets interpret the string\r\n");
        SocketServer::interpret();
        SocketServer::debug("Client {$i} from {$this->clients[$i]->ip} disconnected");
        SocketServer::debug("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        $this->clients[$i]->destroy();
        unset($this->clients[$i]);  
    }       

    public function interpret()
    {
        //Lets get the info to start
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++) // for each client
        {
            if(isset($this->clients[$i]))
            {
                $complete_string = $this->clients[$i]->complete_string;
                SocketServer::debug($complete_string);
                //Do something with the string here

                //Clear the Complete String Variable for next use
                $this->clients[$i]->complete_string = "";
            }
        }
    }

    public function infinite_loop()
    {
        $test = true;
        do
        {
            $test = $this->loop_once();
        }
        while($test);
    }

    public static function debug($text)
    {
        echo("{$text}\r\n");

    }

    function &__get($name)
    {
        return $this->{$name};
    }
}

class SocketServerClient
{
    protected $socket;
    protected $ip;
    protected $hostname;
    protected $server_clients_index;

    public function __construct(&$socket,$i)
    {
        $this->server_clients_index = $i;
        $this->socket = socket_accept($socket) or die("Failed to Accept");
        socket_getpeername($this->socket,$ip);
        $this->ip = $ip;
    }

    public function lookup_hostname()
    {
        $this->hostname = gethostbyaddr($this->ip);
        return $this->hostname;
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        socket_close($this->socket);
    }

    function &__get($name)
    {
        return $this->{$name};
    }

    function __isset($name)
    {
        return isset($this->{$name});
    }
}
```

Comment: what about setting a proper socket time-out value?

Comment: Where in this code would i do that? I have tried countless ways and nothing works :-(

Comment: `socket_set_timeout(resource $stream , int $seconds [, int $microseconds = 0 ] )`.

Some handy example how to terminate connection on timeout:
[#Example 1, php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php)